# Not able to run Cloud functions locally anymore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I came back to my development environment after a month and ran `firebase serve --only functions`. It gave me few messages that I should update my packages. I just followed the directions, and running cloud functions locally on development machine was broken :( I restarted everything from scratch and got all dependencies updated to latest. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with some auth issue that I'm not having any luck :(
I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
```

`packages.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.0.2",
    "google-gax": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I've added my comment to [related Github issue here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/121#issuecomment-507858159)

Comment: You commented on an issue that appears to be a different problem altogether.  I don't see how the error message you're showing here is related to the one originally reported.

Comment: I got into above issues after I removed application_default_credentials.json file as mentioned in linked issue. Earlier I was getting invalid_grant issue reported in GitHub issue.

Comment: What is the relevant output when you run the command with `--debug`?

Comment: Here's link to output with --debug flag on: https://gist.github.com/ptyagicodecamp/34fe4911d1c7bc37cac4525d263fc985

Comment: I don't see any errors in there.  How exactly are you seeing a problem?  I feel like there's some missing information here.  How exactly do you reproduce this problem?

Comment: Switching to passing creds manually using service account key explicitly seems to solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone experiencing similar issue.
For me, switching initializing firebase-admin using `config()` to manually passing service-account-creds solved this problem with authentication.

**Didn't work after taking latest updates**

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

**Working solution**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<project>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: The more common case is to initialize with no parameters, unless you need to use a specific service account that is not the application default service account.  You see it all over in the sample code and docs, and the current environment will provide sensible defaults:  `admin.initializeApp()`

Comment: @DougStevenson: I'm totally agree ! I made sure that my default project is set accordingly to be picked up by firebaseConfig. I'm still not sure why it's having trouble in picking up default config unless I do this manually.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you so much for debugging this issue. Saved my another day :)